# Can we check double creation of a state in Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda, consensus

In my use case, I have a student enrolling to a specific program which in turn creates a student state on the ledger.

Now, if the same student enrolls with same credentials again, I want to avoid it and throw some exception or message.

One solution, I can think of is, I can query the vault before creating the student state and if that student is not found in the ledger than only he is allowed to enroll.

But, this seems like a vague idea. 
Can someone provide a better approach or some other way I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement schema for your state as in this example:

```
class CashState(
        val owner: AbstractParty,
        val pennies: Long) : ContractState, QueryableState {
    override val participants get() = listOf(owner)

    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
        return when (schema) {
            is CashSchemaV1 -> CashSchemaV1.PersistentCashState(
                    this.owner,
                    this.pennies
            )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema")
        }
    }

    override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> = listOf(CashSchemaV1)
}
```

The schema itself:

```
object CashSchema

@CordaSerializable
object CashSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = CashSchema.javaClass, version = 1, mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentCashState::class.java)) {

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "contract_cash_states")
    class PersistentCashState(
            @Column(name = "owner_name", unique=true, nullable = true)
            var owner: AbstractParty?,

            @Column(name = "pennies", nullable = false)
            var pennies: Long

            ) : PersistentState()
}
```

The key point is to make the columns unique, so when you add duplicate value the exception is thrown.

[docs](https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html?highlight=schema#schemas)

Comment: If I need to consumed the old state and produced the new one (in case I need to update pennies)  it is possible?

Comment: @AkkapongKajornwongwattana Yes

Comment: @Алексей  So, if we consume a state and create a new one.. Then also this will work? Because the schema for the old and new state will be the same right?

Comment: @Алексей Suppose we consume an old state and create a new one with almost all the values same. Will this still work?